# Returning a substring's content vs. returning the substring itself

Tags: java, string, performance, substring

I was wondering if this;

```
public String seeColor(String str)
{
    int l = str.length();
    if(l >= 3 && str.substring(0, 3).equals("red")) return "red";
    if(l >= 4 && str.substring(0, 4).equals("blue")) return "blue";
    else return "";
}
```

was faster to compile then this;

```
public String seeColor(String str)
{
    int l = str.length();
    if(l >= 3 && str.substring(0, 4).equals("red")) return str.substring(0, 4);
    if(l >= 4 && str.substring(0, 5).equals("blue")) return str.substring(0, 5);
    else return "";
}
```

or maybe both ways suck and there's another, more efficient approach that I am not aware of?

Comment: Why do you care the difference in compilation time? It will be basically no different. Note that the two examples aren't equivalent, though: the second case is equivalent to simply `return "";` (removing both conditionals; ignoring the null safety) since neither condition can be matched.

Comment: I was doing an exercise on CodingBat, the string `str` will be replaced by other values... I wanted to know which method was the fastest because I am trying to always go for the most performance-friendly approach when solving a problem.

**EDIT:**
Does it really makes no difference which method I use in real-world applications?

Comment: Compile time OR execution time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to `substring` does work to get the generate the substring, so the first choice is more efficient. However, your current code isn't `null` safe (so I would test for `null`) and I would prefer [`String.startsWith(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) like

```
public String seeColor(String str)
{
    if(str == null) return "";
    else if(str.startsWith("red")) return "red";
    else if(str.startsWith("blue")) return "blue";
    else return "";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use below code for better performance:

```
public String seeColor(String str)
{
    if(str.startsWith("red")) return "red";
    else if(str.startsWith("blue")) return "blue";
    else return "";
}
```